# Envoy route match based on environment variables

Tags: envoyproxy

Is it possible to take environment variables into account while doing conditional route-match using envoy ? Here, tag is an environment variable that is available.

Here, the example below does not work but is it possible to use `tag` to do something like what's done below ?

```
          routes:
          - match: { prefix: "/some_path/", {name: {tag}, value: "a"}}
            route: { prefix_rewrite: "/", host_rewrite: {tag}.domain.com, cluster: a }
          - match: { prefix: "/some_path/", {name: {tag}, value: "b"}}
            route: { prefix_rewrite: "/", host_rewrite: {tag}.domain.com, cluster: b }
```

Looking at https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/route/route.proto#envoy-api-msg-route-routematch, it appears that it is only possible to look at fields within the route like prefix and not environment variables ? Alternatively, any alternate suggestions to go about this are also welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've achieved something similar using a combination of meta-data and the [Lua filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_filters/lua_filter).

Add your `tag` values and associated cluster as meta-data to your route and use the [cluster_header](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/route/route.proto.html?highlight=cluster_header) option to provide the cluster name to route to:

```
routes:
 - match:
     prefix: "/"
   metadata:
     filter_metadata:
       envoy.lua:
         a: a
         b: b
   route:
     cluster_header: "upstream-cluster"
```

You can then use the following Lua filter to read the environment variable `TAG` and set the header `upstream-cluster` to the cluster matching that value.

```
http_filters:
- name: envoy.lua
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua
          inline_code: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)

              local metadata = request_handle:metadata()

              local cluster_name = metadata:get(os.getenv("TAG"))

              if cluster_name then
                request_handle:headers():replace("upstream-cluster", cluster_name)
              else
                request_handle:respond(
                  {[":status"] = "502",
                   ["upstream"] = "envoy"},
                   "{\"errorCode\":502,\"reason\":\"no backend cluster found\"}")
              end
            end
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks a lot!